# How to get the selected value from RadioButtonList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a RadioButtonList on my page that is populated via Data Binding

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rb" runat="server">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<asp:Button Text="Submit" OnClick="submit" runat="server" />
```

How do I get the value of the radio button that the user selected in my "submit" method?

Answer (score 53):

The ASPX code will look something like this:

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblist1" runat="server">

    <asp:ListItem Text ="Item1" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text ="Item2" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text ="Item3" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text ="Item4" Value="4" />

    </asp:RadioButtonList>

    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="select value" />
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedValue = rblist1.SelectedValue;
            Response.Write(selectedValue);
        }
```

Comment: Wondering why this is not marked as the correct answer... well... 10 years later.

Answer (score 13):

Using your radio button's ID, try `rb.SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking the answer is correct, but there is a potential problem remaining.
`string test = rb.SelectedValue` is an object and while this implicit cast works. It may not work correction if you were sending it to another method (and granted this may depend on the version of framework, I am unsure) it may not recognize the value.

```
string test = rb.SelectedValue;  //May work fine
SomeMethod(rb.SelectedValue);
```

where `SomeMethod` is expecting a string may not.

Sadly the `rb.SelectedValue.ToString();`  can save a few unexpected issues.

Answer (score -2):

```
string radioListValue = RadioButtonList.Text;
```

Answer (score -5):

`radiobuttonlist.selected <value>`  to process with your code.