# Determine Selected Radiobutton in Constructor in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

Hello,

I have this constructor:

```
public EmployeeCategorizationControl()
        {


        }
```

and many radio buttons:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="selectedYesNoQuestionBlock1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="Question1GotAnswered" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="selectedYesNoQuestionBlock2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Question2GotAnswered">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

In my constructor, how can I determine which radio button is selected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378620/getting-selected-value-from-radiobuttonlist), it may be a duplicate. You'd want to do something similar in your constructor. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With asp.net, interacting with controls in the constructor is not a good idea because of the way the [page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) works. You might want to glance through the page life cycle msdn page and consider `Load` or `Init` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't: the [`Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.request.aspx) isn't available until the **after** constructing the page instance. You have to do it at a later point in [**the page lifecycle**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Before `Load` (during initialization for example) you can only access the selection through the request:

```
protected sub Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    var selection = Request.Form["selectedYesNoQuestionBlock1"];
}
```

`Load` maps the request values to your control objects - from that point on you can access the values directly through the controls:

```
protected sub Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    var selection = selectedYesNoQuestionBlock1.SelectedValue;
}
```