# Radiobuttonlist selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Could someone help me with this solution, stuck on it.

I have a list and filling radiobuttonlist with data, but I can't get selected value when i press submit button.

```
List<CustMobilePhonesEntity> cusMobile = GetCusMobile(Email);


 RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(customerMobile[0].PhoneNumber);

                RadioButtonList1.DataSource = customerMobile;
                RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "PhoneNumber";
                RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "PhoneNumber";
                RadioButtonList1.DataBind();


Label1.Text = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, thank you.

Comment: Are you binding them within `if(! IsPostBack)` condition else the selection would be lost

Comment: a working solution to a related problem
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378620/getting-selected-value-from-radiobuttonlist

Comment: @V4Vemdetta, yes but getting empty :(

Comment: @Olle89 tried, also nothing works, when I add items to radiobuttonlist manually, it works fine, but I need from the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check you are doing it in this fashion (If not the list is again binded with the DataSource when you click submit and the selection is lost)

```
if(! IsPostBack)
{
   RadioButtonList1.DataSource = customerMobile;
   RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "PhoneNumber";
   RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "PhoneNumber";
   RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
}
```

Also since you are binding `RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(customerMobile[0].PhoneNumber);` this won't be required (not clear if anything else).

Also see that `ViewState` is enabled

Comment: RadioButtonList1.Items.Add(customerMobile[0].PhoneNumber); yes, removed that.

Comment: you already have the DataSource why do you want to say `.Add`?

Comment: I removed .Add, that was mistake, but also, can't get selected value

Comment: Are you setting the Label text in handler of button click **or** on page_load ? are you binding it again in that code block ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just bothering you, that was my mistake, since I'm building mobile application, and disabled ViewState on master page, that was problem. Everything works fine now. Thanks a lot!